# Solidity: Can modifiers be marked payable?

Tags: solidity, modifiers

Can I have a modifier that enforces the amount sent by a user in a call to a function, and if it is below a certain amount, throw? 
I want to do something like the following:

```
 uint256 n;

// Set some amount n in the constructor...

modifier checkAmount() payable {
    if(msg.value < n) throw;
    _;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can make your function payable but not the modifier. To note -Payable itself is a modifier.

However, you can use both payable and custom modifier while defining your function and keep msg.value check in the modifier "checkAmount" to throw in case it is less than defined value(n).

Comment: Should we place payable keyword in font of checkAmount modifier in this case, in order for checkAmount to use msg.value?

Answer (score 1):

No, modifier not receiving any ether, You can check if (msg.value < n) throw in your payable function